# Can you win by playing Extremely Destructive Unicorn?

Tags: unstable-unicorns

If you need just 1 more unicorn in your stable to win and you play Extremely Destructive Unicorn, do you win before you have to sacrifice a unicorn?

> When this card enters your Stable, each player (including you) must SACRIFICE a Unicorn card.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer depends on which version of the rules you are playing with, if it's the first printing then you will win as soon as the Extremely Destructive Unicorn enters your stable, but from the second printing onwards the rules were updated to require all effects to resolve first.

As per the [Unstable Games wiki](http://unstablegameswiki.com/index.php?title=UU_Game_Terminology_-_Winning) page on winning the second print run was updated to read as follows:

> **HOW TO WIN** The first person with the required number of Unicorns in their Stable wins. Each Unicorn card counts for 1 Unicorn (unless otherwise stated). *If a player reaches the required number of Unicorns while an effect chain is active, that player is not declared the winner until all links in that effect chain have resolved.*

Which requires that you complete Extremely Destructive Unicorn's effect before being declared winner.

Comment: To add to the previous answer, with the second edition, the game can still be won with the placement of extremely destructive unicorn in probably many ways if you fulfill the effect chain. Off the top of my head, blinding light can negate its effect or unicorn phoenix can allow you to discard a card instead of sacrifice.